# Composer plugin post autoload dump fires too late

Tags: php, plugins, composer-php

I'm trying to write a composer plugin for a modular framework I'm building so that each module is checked for and registered after the autoloader has been dumped.

If I manually run the script via a wrapper in the `"scripts"` part of `composer.json` it seems to work, however the plugin does not fire on the event.

This is a cut down version off the plugin limitted to just the event.

```
<?php

namespace My\Namespace;

use Composer\Composer;
use Composer\Config;
use Composer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Composer\IO\IOInterface;
use Composer\Plugin\PluginEvents;
use Composer\Plugin\PluginInterface;
use Composer\Script\CommandEvent;

class Plugin implements PluginInterface, EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Composer $composer
     * @param IOInterface $io
     */
    public function activate(Composer $composer, IOInterface $io) { }

    /**
     * Once the autoloader has been dumped
     * @param Event $event
     */
    public function onPostAutoloadDump(CommandEvent $event)
    {
        $event->getIO()->write('Autoload dumped.');
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            PluginEvents::COMMAND => [
                ['onPostAutoloadDump' => 0]
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

The plugin documentation is here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md
The event names are here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-names

The composer.json includes

```
{
  ...
  "type": "composer-plugin",
  "extra": {
    "class": "My\\Namespace\\Plugin"
  },
  ...
}
```

I've tried changing `CommandEvent` for a regular `Event` and I've tried changing the event type to `onPreFileDownload`.

Sometimes it will throw:

```
[ErrorException]     
Undefined offset: 0
```

But I can't figure that out either as there is no stack trace.

I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not obvious (at least to me) in the documentation, but all you need to do is this:

To register a method to an event, simply return an array where the key is the event name (listed here) and the value is the name of the method in this class to be called.

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        'post-autoload-dump' => 'methodToBeCalled',
        // ^ event name ^         ^ method name ^                   
    ];
}
```

By default, the priority of an event handler is set to 0. The priorty can be changed by attaching a tuple where the first value is the method name, as before, and the second value is an integer representing the priority. Higher integers represent higher priorityes therefore, priortity 2 is called before priority 1, etc.

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        // Will be called before events with priority 0
        'post-autoload-dump' => ['methodToBeCalled', 1] 
    ];
}
```

If multiple methods should be called, then an array of tupples can be attached to each event. The tupples do not need to include the priority. If it is omitted, it will default to 0.

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        'post-autoload-dump' => [
            ['methodToBeCalled'      ], // Priority defaults to 0
            ['someOtherMethodName', 1], // This fires first
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: You actually only need to change `PluginEvents::COMMAND` to `'post-autoload-dump'`, the rest is ok, but I think this shows a simpler way.

Comment: I'm not sure where this conflicts with the documentation...?

Comment: You are correct, I just found the documentation unhelpful. The example is complex, the event name is hidden by the const (and there is no const I could find for "Command" events (other than the event named `command`) and the method is named almost the same thing as the event. They additionally have priority set in the example (which in the specific example is pointless as the default is 0) confussing things further. I've updated my answer to explain the whole thing. Maybe they'll see this and update theirs too.

Comment: [Done](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4830). Had to rewrite the answer one last time as I realised I got the arrays backwards (not the obvious way around to me).